# How to improve the quality of raster tiles at high zoom levels in Geoserver

Tags: raster, geoserver, tiles, geowebcache

I have been testing the functionality of GeoServer as a WMS raster server and I have noticed that the quality of the tiles at high zoom levels is low. Here is an example of the GeoServer tile vs the original.

GeoServer Tile:

[image: GeoServer Tile]

Original:

[image: Original Tif]

The single pixels need to be view-able for my intended purpose. I thought it might have been due to the png compression so I set that to 0, which did not fix the problem. I created overviews, which improved the visuals at lower zoom levels but the degradation was still present at high zoom levels. I set the interpolation method to bilinear from nearest neighbor which made no difference. I also tried using the GeoWebCache to pre-cache the tiles and this didn't help either. I used the default EPSG:4326 gridset. Does anyone know the reason for my problem and how I can fix it?

Comment: Can you verify that the first image is rendered like that 1:1 by GeoServer and not getting upscaled by your WMS client (GIS or browser)? What tool(s) did you use to get images from the WMS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a full answer but I want to give feedback on the **great** steps and guesses you have taken so far. I hope to update it with "the answer" once we cleared some stuff in comments.

> I thought it might have been due to the png compression so I set that
>   to 0, which did not fix the problem.

PNG compression is lossless so there can not be any visual artifacts due to this.

> I created overviews, which improved the visuals at lower zoom levels
>   but the degradation was still present at high zoom levels.

Overviews are meant for performance improvements (pre-rendering parts so they can be served quickly). That you got better visuals would be dependant on the resampling used.

> I set the interpolation method to bilinear from nearest neighbor which
>   made no difference.

If you want pixels, you *want* nearest neighbor. Anything else will lead to mushy results like in your "bad" screenshot.

> I also tried using the GeoWebCache to pre-cache the tiles and this
>   didn't help either.

That just pre-renders the tiles. The results are the same visually regardless of *when* they were rendered.

> I used the default EPSG:4326 gridset.

That should not be relevant for this problem. You are dealing with artifacts due to resampling on a >1:1 scale.

Comment: it was the inteporation method. I had set it to nearest neighbor in the layer configuration settings and not in the WMS settings, which was the problem. Thank you for the help.

Comment: Sweet! Glad to help :)